How to find the combining standard deviation?
Say we choose $n_1$ numbers randomly from a binomial distribution with success probability $p_1$, also we select $n_2$ numbers randomly from a binomial distribution with success probability $p_2$ and so on:
$binornd(n_1, p_1)$
$binornd(n_2, p_2)$
...
$binornd(n_k, p_k)$
So now we have $n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_k$ numbers. I am trying to find if these numbers now correspond to another binomial distribution with success probability $p_{tot}$, as:
$ binornd(n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_k, p_{tot})$
how can I relate $p_{tot}$ to $(n_1, n_2,...,n_k,p_1,p_2,...,p_k)$
$p_{tot} \sim (n_1, n_2,...,n_k,p_1,p_2,...,p_k)$

I suggest:  work this out for $k=2$.  Note:  the question in the header is not the same as the question in the body of the post.

The title of the question does not match the description. Secondly, do you mean that you sample 1 random variable from $\text{Bin} (n_i,p_i) for each $i = 1,2,\cdots,k$? Or $n_i$ random variables from each $\text{Bin} (n_i,p_i)$?

@Television
Hello, Thanks for the comments, let me clarify the question again
binornd($n_1$, $p_1$) generates a list of $n_1$ numbers from the binomial distribution with the success probability $p_1$
we keep this list, and generate k more lists with
binornd($n_i$, $p_i$)
if we combine all the lists we have, then we would have a list of ($n_1 + n_2 + .... + n_k$) numbers
I want to find if these trials are related to a new distribution with the success probability $p_tot$, as if we chose $n_1 + n_2 + .... + n_k$ numbers from the binomial distribution with success probability $p_tot$

@lulu Hello, and thanks for the comment. You are right. The title doesn't match the question, but since I derived the probabilities from the standard deviations, it was on my mind then. And about your suggestion, I don't have any intuition about the problem so I don't know how to solve it even for k=2, If you have any suggestion, I would be glad to hear, thanks
